# Extract text from element-less section of page

Tags: java, jsoup

I currently have the following section of HTML code from a web page:

```
<td class="movieclass">
<b>Cinema 1</b>
    10.30 AM. + 12.45 + 3.00 + 5.15 + 7.30 + 9.45 + 12.00 MN.
<br />

<b>Cinema 2</b>
    3.00 + 5.15 + 7.30 + 9.45 + (12.00 MN. THRS./FRI.)
<br />

<b>Cinema 3</b>
    2.30 + 4.45 + 7.00 + 9.15  + (12.15 PM. + 11.30 PM. THRS./FRI.)
<br />

<b>Cinema 4</b>
    11.30 AM. + 2.00 + 4.30 + 7.00 + 9.30 + 12.00 MN.
<br />

<b>Cinema 5</b>
    10.30 AM. + 1.00 + 3.30 + 6.00 + 8.30 + 11.00 PM.
<br />
</td>
```

I'm trying to use jsoup to try and extract the time, but for a specific cinema. I'm assuming if the times lines were within paragraphs (p tags) I could use the following for extracting:

```
Elements movieTime = doc.select("a:contains(Cinema 3) + p");
```

However, in the code above the lines with times have no tags around them. Is there a way of extracting the times line for a certain cinema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to create a jsoup document with the HTML of the page:

```
String doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com").get().html();
```

Then did some string replacement on the document:

```
doc = doc.replaceAll("<b>","<p>");
doc = doc.replaceAll("</b>","</p><p>");
```

The replacing seems a bit extreme since it is going through the whole document, but I just need some tags around the section I needed to extract. Finally the extraction:

```
Document newDoc = Jsoup.parse(doc);
String movieTimes = newDoc.select("p:contains(Cinema 2) + p").text();
System.out.println(movieTimes); //Should print only text within <p> after Cinema 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is always a way to do this manually if the document you provided ALWAYS retains the same structure. Then you can simply read all document to some sort of List. For e.g. ArrayList.

Then iterate through that list and use if statements to check

```
if (line.get(0).equals("Cinema 1")) {
  timeOfCinema1 = line.get(1);
}
```

But this is the most simplier and not "nice" way to do this. You can use `Map<String, String>` to map the lines, or create an object which will hold the structure of the documents.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's one method I was considering, but like you mentioned it's not really nice. Posting another solution below.